# Filtering parameters or skipping test when parameters have certain values

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I want to  skip a test if a fixture parameter has a certain value. See this example:

```
import random
from itertools import combinations, starmap

import pytest


def save_divide(num, denom):
    return divide(num, denom) if denom else UNDEFINED


UNDEFINED = None


def divide(num, denom):
    return num / denom


def test_save_divide(fractions):
    for num, denom in fractions:
        result = save_divide(num, denom)
        assert result == (num / denom if denom else UNDEFINED)


# Here I would like to skip intervals that include 0, instead of
# setting the value for `interval` manually.
# I know I can just check for `denom == 0`. This is just an artifact
# of this MWE. In my actual code such a check is not possible within
# the body of the test function.
@pytest.mark.parametrize("interval", [(1, 5)])
def test_divide(fractions):
    for num, denom in fractions:
        assert divide(num, denom) == num / denom


@pytest.fixture
def fractions(interval):
    def stochastic_flip(a, b):
        return (a, b) if random.randint(0, 1) else (b, a)

    nums = range(*interval)
    return set(starmap(stochastic_flip, combinations(nums, r=2)))


@pytest.fixture(params=[(-2, 2), (1, 5)])
def interval(request):
    return request.param
```

I did not find anything in the documentation about skipping based on fixture values. Is this possible?

Comment: If a check for the parameter is not possible, how would you detect that a parameter shall be skipped? There shall be some place (in a function that provides the parameters, in a skip marker in the parameters, or in the test itself) where some check has to be made, so I'm not sure what you mean here.

Comment: Some tests are ok with `denom == 0`, some are not. The fixture providing `fractions` does not know of that. There could be a feature like `mark.parametrize(skip=lambda interval: <check for zeros>)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not completely sure if I understand your use case, but I assume that you want to skip tests with a parameter from `fraction` which is based on `interval` containing a zero (or meet some other condition). Provided this is what you need, you could make a separate fixture based on both `interval` and `fraction` which does that check and skips tests accordingly:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def fractions_no_zero(interval, fractions):
    if interval[0] <= 0 < interval[1]:    # will skip (-2, 2)
        pytest.skip("Denominator can be zero")
    else:
        return fractions

def test_divide(fractions_no_zero):
    for num, denom in fractions_no_zero:
        assert divide(num, denom) == num / denom
```

Note that in this case, e.g. if you base your fixture on two "base" fixtures, you will only get the matching values, e.g. the value for `interval` on which `fractions` is based upon.